# Installation cherrypy Mac

Tags: macos, installation, cherrypy

I have problem to import (and apparently with installation) Cherrypy on Mac. I used 'pip', python install of setup.py, and it works (I also check the folder cherrypy in the Python folder) but when I try to import cherrypy, it doesn't work :

```
ImportError: No module named 'cherrypy'
```

Did someone had the same problem and found a solution ?

Thank you.

T.

Comment: You must be running your scripts with a different Python install, not the one used to install CherryPy

Comment: Hum, I don't really understand because I have only one version of Python on my computer. I have a PC with two version of Python (32 and 64 bits) and I had no problem with the installation.

Comment: The only idea left is wrong permissions.

Comment: I already tried with sudo too :(

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem yesterday. I was using `pip` and there was import error and other errors. So, I uninstalled cherrypy (`sudo pip uninstall cherrypy`) and then used `sudo easy_install cherrypy`. It worked for me!

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll tried this evening and I'll tell you if it's works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
sudo easy_install cherrypy
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `sudo easy_install cherrypy` make sure you have only one version of python. on macOs Sierra version 2.7 of python is installed by default. but if you have 2 versions of python like i have, you have to make sure which `easy_install` that want to use to install `cherrypy`. I have python 3.6 on my mac and also have python 2.7 on it, and if you want to install cherrypy on 3.6 python.

1. locate the `easy_install` on terminal `$ locate easy_install`
2. get the result like this

`/usr/bin/easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.6`

now you know which `easy_install` app that you want to use to install `cherypy` based on python version that to use.

3. if you to install `cherrypy` on 3.6 python type on terminal

   `$ sudo easy_install-3.6 cherrypy`

and if you want to install `cherrypy` on 2.7 python just type

```
`$ sudo easy_install cherrypy`
```

it will install based on the version that we want

hope its help :)